# Programmatically log in a user

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization, bootstrapping, external-scripts

I am trying to authenticate users as below. I don't get any error, but it doesn't log in users.

autoLogin.php is located in the root folder. Visiting http://example.com/drupal8/autoLogin.php shows me the *Login required* page every time.

```php
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

$uid = 1; 
$user = Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1); 
$kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);
user_login_finalize($user);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: The code should throw an error about the `user_login_finalize()` function, since the User module hasn't been loaded, yet.

Answer (score 1):

The code shown in the question would throw an error about `user_login_finalize()` not being defined. The code isn't loading the User module and the `DrupalKernel` class doesn't load any module.

I generally use the code shown in [authorize.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21authorize.php/9.0.x) as guideline on how to bootstrap and programmatically log in a user. In this case, to programmatically log in the user whose ID is 1, I would use the following code.

```php
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$autoloader = (require_once 'autoload.php');

try {
  $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
  $kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
  $kernel->boot();

  // A route is required for route matching.
  $request->attributes->set(RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT, new Route('<none>'));
  $request->attributes->set(RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_NAME, '<none>');
  $kernel->preHandle($request);

  if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    $request->setSession($kernel->getContainer()->get('session'));
  }
} catch (HttpExceptionInterface $e) {
  $response = new Response('', $e->getStatusCode());
  $response->prepare($request)->send();
  exit;
}

\Drupal::moduleHandler()->addModule('system', 'core/modules/system');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->addModule('user', 'core/modules/user');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->load('system');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->load('user');
if ($account = User::load(1)) {
  \Drupal::currentUser()->setAccount($account);
  // Add your code.
  $response->setStatusCode(200);
  $response->send();
}
```

Since it seems you are trying to access a specific page after logging in the user #1, it's probable you need to change the two lines following the *A route is required for route matching.* comment and use a different route name.

Comment: As side note, I would rather not bootstrap Drupal from an external script. I would create a custom module with its own route which would execute the code I need. Even Drupal core stopped to use an external script (cron.php) to run the cron tasks and instead added a route for running them (system.cron).

Comment: Yes, I am planning to create a custom module but I want to make sure it's working beforehand. It gives `Error: Call to a member function setStatusCode() on null` so I added `$response = $kernel->handle($request);` right after 'Add your code' line. It doesn't log me in though. It still shows the app as unauthenticated.